# Edit error message html : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs, template-override

Where can I find HTML to add `role="alert"` to error messages in magento. For example, when a user provides a wrong zip code on checkout page this error message shows up.

`<div for="postcode" generated="true" class="mage-error" id="postcode-error">Please enter a valid zip code (Ex: 90602 or 90602-1234).</div>`

I would like to add an attribute to the above div tag. Magento version is 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

I changed a core file to add an attribute to error messages `/lib/web/jquery/jquery.validate.js`

```
- .attr({"for": this.idOrName(element), generated: true})
+ .attr({"for": this.idOrName(element), generated: true, role: "alert"})
```